# Batch : How can I create a shortcut when it does not exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi I am newly in the batch/command line.

I want to create a shortcut of an application only if the shortcut/file doesn't already exist. I wrote the part that create the short that works if it is not in the condition IF, but when it is inside, nothing happens.

Here is the code :

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Tks.lnk" (
    echo file
)   else (
    echo not file
    
    set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

    echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
    echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Tks.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\000_DF_P\SF - Tks.accdb" >> %SCRIPT%
    echo oLink.IconLocation = "destination_icon"  >> %SCRIPT%
    echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

    cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
    del %SCRIPT%
)
pause
```

Thank you

Comment: But you can call LNK-creation from batch without temporary file: **mshta VBScript:Execute("Set Shell=CreateObject(""WScript.Shell""):Set Link=Shell.CreateShortcut(""LinkName.lnk""):Link.TargetPath=""c:\1\1.exe"":Link.WorkingDirectory=""c:\1"":Link.Save:close"^)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues to avoid and other ways to do this but just to correct your attempt.

Move the definitions to the start and escape internal else ) using `^)`

```
@echo off

set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

if exist "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Tks.lnk" (
    echo file
)   else (
    echo not file
    
    echo Dim oWS >> %SCRIPT%
    echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^) >> %SCRIPT%
    echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Tks.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile^) >> %SCRIPT%
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\000_DF_P\SF - Tks.accdb" >> %SCRIPT%
    echo oLink.IconLocation = "destination_icon"  >> %SCRIPT%
    echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

    cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
    del %SCRIPT%
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for your a help :)  however it does not work to create the shortcut. Here is what I get in the console :  Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'oWS'. Do you have any idea what I should change

Comment: sorry it works perfectly, it misses one ^). I will ask a new question on the batch/ line command. I am completly newly